# How to automatically add user and assign random password to the users?

Tags: bash, scripts

I want to write a script file which will automatically create user and randomly generate passwords. The script that I've written is bellow.

I am still learning so I dont know much. I think I've found what I'm looking for but I am not sure about it. [Found solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150882/how-to-automatically-add-user-account-and-password-with-a-bash-script).

Can anyone please help me with this?

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/home/dfs/user"
while IFS= read line
do
     echo "$time"
done < "$file"

useradd Daniel
passwd daniel
```

Answer (score 0):

With a following script you can generate a random password from a dictionary:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
generate_random() {
    RANDOM_NUMBER=$(/usr/bin/perl -e 'print int(rand(60453));')
}

generate_random
randomWord1=$(head -$RANDOM_NUMBER ./dictionary.txt | tail -1)

generate_random
randomWord2=$(head -$RANDOM_NUMBER ./dictionary.txt | tail -1)

generate_random
randomWord3=$(head -$RANDOM_NUMBER ./dictionary.txt | tail -1)

echo "$randomWord1 $randomWord2 $randomWord3"
```

In this case, create a password concatenating 3 random words from the dictionary.

If you want to use it, you have to change the following data:

- name of the dictionary file: dictonary.txt in the example
- number of words in the dictionary: 60453 in the example

Then you can use it inside a new script to create users and assign them the password generated. This is an example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

PwdGen="./generate_random_password.sh"

# define CSV separator
IFS=";"

while read username FullName
do

    useradd -m -c "$FullName" $username

    # Generate random password
    Pwd=$($PwdGen)

    # assign the password 
    usermod --password $(echo "$Pwd" | openssl passwd -1 -stdin) $username

done < users_in.csv
```

This script use the first script (`generate_random_password.sh`) to generate random password, the create users reading them from input `file users_in.csv` and assign them the password generated.

Comment: will try and let you know.